# Peculiar behaviour of a rod and sphere

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

I found a metal rod lying on the floor and I found out that it sticks when brought closer to a steel sphere like a magnet, but, neither the sphere nor the rod is a magnet. More astonishing is that the sphere sticks to the rod to only a single side of the rod and not the other side as if it was a uni-directional magnet, but none of those two objects interact with any other metal objects and the rod and the sphere are not repelled by a permanent magnet either. Please can anybody explain this anomaly.

Comment: Without knowing the constituents of those materials, all the answers will be with a significant uncertainty. "any other metals objects", only ferromagnetic metals like iron should be used. If they are inert with a magnet there is a possible electrostatic interaction.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: But what kind of an electrostatic interaction it could be?

Comment: One of the components may have a charge, if its really all of metal, the charge should vanish, if you touch it long enough. if only one side reacts it can not be metal trough  or its not electrostatic

Comment: Welcome Rahimullah to Physics Stack Exchange.  You haven't given us much to go on. Was the rod lying on an indoor floor or outside on the ground?  How long was the rod lying in that position? Was the rod exposed to sunlight? Is the floor cold? Neither the rod nor the sphere are repelled by a permanent magnet, but are they attracted? Is the rod attracted to the sphere before touching it, even if only a millimetre away, or does it stick only after touching? Are you saying that the rod does not stick to other iron objects that are attracted to other magnetic fields (e.g. the permanent magnet)?